# How applications are managed in Linux?

Tags: linux, service, system

I am looking for design suggestions/documents etc. which contains specifics of system applications management in Linux (Ubuntu, Debian etc.)

Can you please point to a source of information or suggest a design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean by *system applications management* (certainly it can mean several different things).

In practice, [Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) have some [package management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) to deal with that issue. [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) or [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (etc....) is in charge of starting/stopping/managing [daemons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) and [servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_%28computing%29). Its configuration is related to packaging.

Read also [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) and [How To Package For Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian) and [Debian new Maintainer guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/) etc...

If you are coding some service application, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and about [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) & [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html)

Also, study the source code of relevant system applications (similar to the one you are dreaming of), since Linux is generally (mostly) [free software](http://www.fsf.org/).

Comment: I mean: system is started with bunch of applications and their corresponding configurations. As you pointed init/systemd working must be searched for.